# Should we add an (AES) tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I was recently writing [a question about AES](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110754/73844) and noticed there's no [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) tag.

There are [60 questions with AES within them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=aes+is%3Aq) so it begs the question, should we add an [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) tag and add it to these questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's use the [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) as a proxy for [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes)...

If your code implements or significantly "is" a linked list, then tag it as [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list). If your code just uses a linked list to do what it does, then it should not be tagged [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list).

If your code requires the skill of a [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) expert to get a review, then yes, use it.

The same applies to [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) - if the code just uses [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) to get done what it needs to do, then it's not really an [aes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aes) question.

On the other hand, your specific question, is pretty much on the fence, and it would benefit from expert review... so, I say:

### Yes - tag it

On the other hand, most of the other questions mentioning AES, should not be tagged with it.

So, questions like this should be tagged:

- [AES implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101272/aes-implementation?s=1|1.7809)

But, questions like this should not:

- [Encrypting a binary stream with RSA + AES in counter mode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/103926/encrypting-a-binary-stream-with-rsa-aes-in-counter-mode?s=20|0.9839)

Comment: In that case, do you think there is any value adding the tag to so few questions? If you search for "aes implementation", you only get [21 results](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=aes+implementation), I would be that *not all* of them would actually be applicable.

Comment: @EBrown - if you add "is:q" you get only 14 questions, but there are other questions without "implementation" in them that are also relevant. It's also not about the numbers, in this case. It's about the content. AES is a discrete algorithm. The only real question, is whether it is a big enough subset of [tag:cryptography] to get a specific tag. I would say that it is.

Comment: Additionally, if we have [tag:caesar-cipher] we can have [tag:aes]

Comment: There might also be some "rijndael" questions that could be tagged with this?

Comment: @SimonForsberg That would be understandable, Rijndael is just a more specific version of AES.